# jQuery .each finding only first value

Tags: jquery, each

I'm working on a simple jQuery script that would take values from the data attributes of the columns and output them as an array. I can only get the code to keep repeating the first value.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='percent-column'>
        <div class="inputdiv" data-value="67">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Number" value="25"/>
            <button class="btn_output">Click to Show Output</button>
        </div>


        <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='percent-column'>
        <div class="inputdiv" data-value="34">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Number" value="25"/>
            <button class="btn_output">Click to Show Output</button>
        </div>


        <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='percent-column'>
        <div class="inputdiv" data-value="93">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Number" value="25"/>
            <button class="btn_output">Click to Show Output</button>
        </div>


        <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
        $('.percent-column').each(function(){
                var findValue = $('.inputdiv').attr('data-value');
                var valArray = [];
                valArray.push(findValue);
                console.log(valArray);
        });
});
```

This outputs 
67
67
67

Comment: `$('.inputdiv')` looks for all elements with class `inputdiv` on the page, but it serves no purpose in the loop because you don't reference "the current element" in any way. You probably want something like `$(this).find('.inputdiv')` - referencing `this` will make the loop relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.inputdiv').attr('data-value');
```

in the loop is still searching the entire dom.

use

```
$(this).find('.inputdiv').attr('data-value');
```

for the current loop iteration.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){     
        $('.percent-column').each(function(){
                var findValue = $(this).find('.inputdiv').attr('data-value');
                var valArray = [];
                valArray.push(findValue);
                console.log(valArray);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='percent-column'>
        <div class="inputdiv" data-value="67">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Number" value="25"/>
            <button class="btn_output">Click to Show Output</button>
        </div>


        <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='percent-column'>
        <div class="inputdiv" data-value="34">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Number" value="25"/>
            <button class="btn_output">Click to Show Output</button>
        </div>


        <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>

    <div class='percent-column'>
        <div class="inputdiv" data-value="93">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Number" value="25"/>
            <button class="btn_output">Click to Show Output</button>
        </div>


        <div class="progress">
                <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, Adrian. As I was thinking about this late last night I suspected that was what I was doing wrong, but I still appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

$('.inputdiv') finds all the elements with class="inputdiv".
If you want to get the .inputdiv element inside .percent-column element then use 
.percent-column element as the scope when searcing for .inputdiv

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
   $('.percent-column').each(function(){
       var findValue = $('.inputdiv', $(this)).attr('data-value');
       ///...
   });
});
```